# Android: Receive broadcast for connected Bluetooth Low Energy devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

My app automates stuff on the device, based on rules. So e.g. bluetooth device xyz connected - turn volume on. That works fine. However I want to extend it to include bluetooth low energy devices. Currently it only supports devices that I can also see as paired in the system's bluetooth settings.

Does anybody have an idea on how to monitor BTLE devices as well?

So I do not want to communicate with these devices myself, I just want to know if another application communicates with one (so receive a broadcast like with the classic BT devices).

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer for this ?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not.